# Get stacktrace from inside Code.eval_quoted

Tags: elixir, stack-trace

Is it possible to get a full stacktrace or see on which line an error gets throw when evaluating a quoted block in Elixir?

For example I have this module:

```ex
defmodule Test do
  def trySomeQuotedCode() do
    quote do
      IO.puts "line 1"
      IO.puts "line 2"
      5/0
    end
    |> evalMyQuoted
  end

  def evalMyQuoted(quoted) do
    Code.eval_quoted(quoted)
  end
end
```

But if you execute it, you see this:

[image: stack trace until 'quoted' call]

It shows there was an `ArithmeticError` with `:erlang./(5, 0)`, which is correct but it does not show where in the quoted code. With this small example it's still easy to find where the error lies in the code, but if this quoted code is a lot bigger or more advanced it may not be so trivial.

So, for this example, is it possible to get the stacktrace to say that error is on *"line 3"* inside the evaluation of the quoted part? Or perhaps get the line number as a return value from `Code.eval_quoted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** Use [location: :keep](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2-options).

---

You can define your `quote` inside a macro, like this:

```
defmodule Test do
    defmacro my_quote do
        quote do
            IO.puts "line 1"
            IO.puts "line 2"
            5/0
        end
    end

    def try_quote do
        my_quote()  # Line 11
    end
end
```

Now calling `Test.try_quote`:

```
iex(7)> Test.try_quote
line 1
line 2
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    test.exs:11: Test.try_quote/0
```

So we get line where the quote was called, which is better, but not yet what we wanted.

A solution then could be to use the macro to define a function for us, like this:

```
defmodule TestMacro do
  defmacro my_quote do
    quote do
      def my_function do
        IO.puts "line 1"
        IO.puts "line 2"
        5/0 # Line 7
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  import TestMacro
  my_quote # Line 15
end
```

Now calling `Test.my_function` gives us:

```
line 1
line 2
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    test.exs:15: Test.my_function/0
```

Which is still the line where the macro was called! But now if we change the quote definition (line 3) to

```
quote location: :keep do
```

We finally get the exact line where the error occurs:

```
line 1
line 2
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    test.exs:7: Test.my_function/0
```

Comment: The "location: :keep" was indeed the thing i was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`location: :keep`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2-options) option in the call to [`Kernel.quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2).

Comment: Gabriel Prá also already answered with the "location: :keep", but the link you gave is also quite helpful!